# How to use retina.js with require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Is there a way to use [retina.js v2.0](https://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) as AMD module for [require.js](http://requirejs.org)?

I have tried to do it like this:

main.js file:

```
paths: {
  retina: 'path/to/retina'
}
shim: {
   retina : {
     exports: "retina"
   }
}

requirejs(['retina']);
```

HTML file - regular image tag with source to low-res image. Retina.js is loaded through require.js, but image is not swapped for @2x image. 
This solution doesn't work.

Attempt 2 - try it without shim - it doesn't work.

Attempt 3 - add `data-rjs="path/to/image@2x.png"` to image tag - it doesn't work

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using retina.js as an AMD module?  Have you tried it as a shim?  How have you tried using it with require.js?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: I have updated a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I have found an answer

Shim must be defined this way:

```
shim: {
  "retina" : {
    exports: "retinajs"
  }
}
```

When you require this script, you must do it this way:

```
requirejs(['retina'], function(retina) {
  retina();          
});
```

This works **only** on images that have `data-rjs` attribute defined.

`<img src="image.png" data-rjs="image@2x.png" />`